# Using Multiple Buttons with ActionEvent

Tags: java, actionevent

I already got some help on this, but now when I press the buttons, nothing happens. I want text to show up when you click a button. If it is a layout problem, which one should I use? `FlowLayout` does not work as well with this program, as it distorts the buttons.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Option3 extends Frame implements WindowListener,ActionListener
{
    Label l1;
    Label l2;
    Label l3;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;
    Button b3;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Option3 o3 = new Option3("Press a Button");
        o3.setSize(700,350);
        o3.setVisible(true);
    }
    public Option3(String option3)
    {
        super(option3);
        setLayout(null);
        addWindowListener(this);

        Label l1 = new Label();
        l1 = new Label();
        l1.setBounds(50,150,125,50);
        l1.setVisible(true);
        add(l1);

        Label l2 = new Label();
        l2 = new Label();
        l2.setBounds(275,150,125,50);
        l2.setVisible(true);
        add(l2);

        Label l3 = new Label();
        l3 = new Label();
        l3.setBounds(500,150,125,50);
        l3.setVisible(true);
        add(l3);

        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1 = new Button();
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b1.setBounds(25,100,175,175);
        add(b1);

        Button b2 = new Button();
        b2 = new Button();
        addWindowListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b2.setBounds(250,100,175,175);
        add(b2);

        Button b3 = new Button();
        b3 = new Button();
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b3.setBounds(475,100,175,175);
        add(b3);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == b1)
        {
            l1.setText("You pressed button 1.");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == b2)
        {
            l2.setText("You pressed button 2.");
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == b3)
        {
            l3.setText("You pressed button 3.");
        }
    }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == b1) {
        // do stuff
    } else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

`e.getSource()` returns the object reference that triggered the event.

Comment: First if you haven't changed it, you need to add an action listener to your buttons, e.g. `b1.addActionListener(this);`.  Second, all your class variables are still `null` because you're creating local objects `Button b1 = new Button();` instead of initializing the class variables `b1 = new Button();`.  Third, you're setting the width and height of the label to 0,0.  Resize it with `l1.setBounds(10,10,50,50);` x,y = 10,10 and width,height = 50,50. You can play around with those values.

Comment: I posted my updated code -- maybe you could help once you see the whole thing.

Comment: You need to remove your local variables entirely. `Label l1 = new Label();`, etc. should not be there.  You are still adding the local variables to the frame and not initializing the class variables because of the way variable scoping works in java.

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use the actionCommand:

```
//after object creation:
firstButton.setActionCommand("upper");
firstButton.addActionListener(this);// if this object is the listener
secondButton.addActionListener(this);// if this object is the listener
secondButton.setActionCommand("lower");
```

And then in your actionPerformed():

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  String command = event.getActionCommand();
  if("upper".equals(command)){
    //Do something
  } else if("lower".equals(command)){
    //Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: This solved it, but there was a simpler answer below you. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @YoungDeezie the difference is, that you have to keep your buttons global with the getSource()-solution, while you can define your buttons where you want, if you use my solution. but it works as well!

Comment: You will never jump in the "actionPerformed- Method. You must register the Listener on every button. Something like this:   b3.addActionListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I prefer **Swing** over **AWT**. The following code shows a JFrame with 3 buttons. If you click a button, it would show a dialog box telling which button you clicked.

> I've used **Lambda Expressions**. So, you must have jdk8 to run the
>   following code. Don't rate down if this code doesn't work for you.
>   Just go & grab jdk8.

If you're not comfortable with Lambda Expression. Then follow these instruction:-
 
Make an inner class `ListenForButton implements ActionListener` .
 Write logics in overriden method definition. Then add this listener to your button as
 `b1.addActionListener(new ListenForButton())`

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Option3 extends JFrame {

    JButton b1, b2, b3;
    JPanel jp1;

    private void initComponents() {
        jp1 = new JPanel();
        add(jp1);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        b1 = new JButton("Button1");
        b1.addActionListener(e -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Button1 clicked");
        });
        jp1.add(b1);

        b2 = new JButton("Button2");
        b2.addActionListener(e -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Button2 clicked");
        });
        jp1.add(b2);

        b3 = new JButton("Button3");
        b3.addActionListener(e -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Button3 clicked");
        });
        jp1.add(b3);
        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Option3("Press a Button").setVisible(true);
    }

    public Option3(String option3) {
        super(option3);
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```